# Copy files to inkscape extenstion folder doesn't work

Tags: python, inkscape

I copy file extension to `C:\Users\ganuo\AppData\Roaming\inkscape\extensions` and restart Inkscape but I don't see my script showing up in the *Extensions* menu bar. Clicking on *Manage Extensions* I get this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Inkscape\share\inkscape\extensions\inkman\inkman\manage_extensions.py", line 29, in <module>
    from inkex import gui
  File "C:\Program Files\Inkscape\share\inkscape\extensions\inkex\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .extensions import *
  File "C:\Program Files\Inkscape\share\inkscape\extensions\inkex\extensions.py", line 34, in <module>
    from .elements import (
  File "C:\Program Files\Inkscape\share\inkscape\extensions\inkex\elements\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ._parser import SVG_PARSER, load_svg
  File "C:\Program Files\Inkscape\share\inkscape\extensions\inkex\elements\_parser.py", line 30, in <module>
    from lxml import etree
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lxml'
```

`pip install lxml` doesn't work.

Do you know what makes this happen?

Inkscape 1.2.2 (732a01da63, 2022-12-09)

[image]

Comment: Weirdly, it seems [Inkscape extensions still use Python2](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/Extension_requirements#Python_Extensions) !?

Comment: @ekhumoro: No. Starting from Inkscape 1.0 (May 2020), Inkscape extensions use Python 3.